# Python: Is there an inverse for ndarray.flatten('F')?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example:

```
from numpy import *
x = array([[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print x.flatten('F')
>>>[1 3 5 2 4 6]
```

Is it possible to get `[[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` from `[1 3 5 2 4 6]`?

Answer (score 27):

```
>>> a = numpy.array((1, 3, 5, 2 ,4, 6))
>>> a.reshape(2, -1).T
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 18):

This seems a little more straightforward. Just pass the original shape back into reshape.

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]).flatten().reshape((3, 2))
```

---

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

And for your Fortran ordering, pass 'F' for the reshape order:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]).flatten('F').reshape((3, 2), order='F')
```

---

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an elegant pure python oneliner to this problem:

```
arr2d = [[arr1d[i+j*width] for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).